# What is the minimal accepted value of imageBase?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, portable-executable, machine-code

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_optional_header32?redirectedfrom=MSDN), ImageBase should be `a multiple of 64K bytes` but modify
at 0x38, 0x00400000 to 0x00000000 not work but it works with 0x00900000 and 0x00010000.
( I also changed the address of (8) and (10) accordingly)

Questions :

1. Why it is not working with an imageBase of 0x00000000 ?
2. What is the minimal correct value of imageBase ?

[image]

Comment: Low addresses are typically reserved to catch null pointers. Haven't checked the specification though.

Comment: @Jester ok so the specs should be `a multiple of 64K bytes superior or equal to 1` ? (and 64K is in fact 64kio)

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6242/windows-why-is-the-imagebase-default-0x400000  seems relevant.

Comment: @Michael thx, `imagebase base must be multiples of 64k if base:0 is used exe will be having an image base of 0x10000` and that effectively true while not defined in specs. If imageBase is set to 0x00000000, it will behave like it was 0x00010000 (so all address should be compliant with 0x00010000 (ie; (10) FF1544000100))